# Facing issue to show multiple error message using trigger in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am using trigger to generate error message during insert null value in php using MySQL database.

Here is the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `soap_account_add`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `soap_account_add_insert_trigger`$$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `soap_account_add_insert_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `soap_account_add_insert` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.client_code IS NULL OR NEW.client_code = '') THEN
        SET NEW='Error: Client Code can not be empty. ';
  END IF;
  IF (NEW.msisdn IS NULL OR NEW.msisdn = '') THEN
        SET NEW='Error: MSISDN can not be empty. ';
  END IF;
  IF (NEW.account_ref IS NULL OR NEW.account_ref = '') THEN
        SET NEW='Error: Account can not be empty. ';
  END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Below is my file format to upload:

```
client_code,account_ref,msisdn,msisdn_type
2161304,1013322512,01944689009,NK
2160417,1013318996,01944675008,NK
2202905,1013762565,,AX
2387742,,01982074930,NK
,1015732958,01982074930,NK
```

But, I am getting only one error message:

```
Variable 'new' can't be set to the value of 'Error: MSISDN can not be empty.'
```

i am not getting the other two error message. Is there any issue in my trigger script??

Comment: I've made maybe 3 triggers in my life so I don't want to post an answer, but I'm fairly certain you have to specify the column you are setting for `NEW`.

Comment: can you please explain where i have to change..

Comment: Well, I don't know how your table is set up, but you need to specify a column you want to set the error message too, just like you did in the IF statement. Something like `SET NEW.mycolumn = 'Error: blah blah...'`.